# Unity BoxCollider2D Pass through some objects while retaining trigger properties

Tags: unity-game-engine, triggers, collision

i have a goomba and i am trying to make it so that the goomba can pass through mario, but still be used as a trigger, while not falling through the ground. i am using a Boxcollider2D, in the physics 2D tab i can disable mario, so the goomba walks through him, but then the goomba does not trigger the event i need, if i set the goomba to trigger it falls through the ground, is there a way to have it so the goomba passes through mario and not the ground, as well as triggering events for mario? similar to a box collision in unreal engine 4

Comment: In the boxcollider inspector is a checkbox calles isTrigger, check that and use OnTriggerEnter/Exit functions

Comment: This way the collision is disabled while being able to check if the boxes overlap

Comment: i do this and the goomba falls through the floor, because im using a tilemap

Comment: Then add a second box collider normally and enable only collision for the floor

Comment: Sorry, forgot the mention that, thats the way a do it all the time

Comment: how can i enable only collision for the floor box collider, otherwise the other box collider is still gonna hit mario

Comment: In the collision matrix, just make sure that the goomba is on its own layer

Comment: To access to the collision matrix go to Project Settings -> Physics->Layer Collision Matrix. Also remember to attach different layers to Mario and Goomba.

Comment: Ah, didnt mention that as well, im sorry

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer myself, don't need another box collider2D either, you just make a physics.overlapshere and that detects even if they have collision disabled between the two gameobjects